# Is it possible to customize a wordpress post from outside dashboard(Something like site.com/post-type/post/?e=post_id)?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts, theme-development

My question is -

1. Is it possible to customize a wordpress post without using wp-admin dashboard?
2. If so, how do I need to generate url for the post?
3. How to submit the data which is edited through the form?

Comment: Yes! Put a look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/ and here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/

Comment: To reply since changing your title: You have several ways. You can create a file and include it with a init add_action in your functions.php.. after, you do some codes in your file for activate it when you get "e=" and you have good authentification. You can create a page in your admin, create a page template and make some codes for accessibility, etc...

Answer (score 0):

### Is it possible to customize a wordpress post without using wp-admin dashboard?

Not the way you're wanting it, to answer this more thoroughly:

#### Is it possible to customize a wordpress post from outside dashboard(Something like site.com/post-type/post/?e=post_id)?

Not out of the box, there is no frontend post editing UI in WordPress. You would have to build it yourself ( and many people do )

#### Can I Build One?

Yes! But you would need to implement the UI yourself, and you would need to process that data and pass it to `wp_insert_post`, and handle the security.

You could use the REST API, and let that handle the security, simplifying things. That's what the block editor does.

### If so, how do I need to generate url for the post?

As mentioned above, there is no frontend post editing UI out of the box

### How to submit the data which is edited through the form?

You'd have to construct the form and the handler for it yourself. `wp_insert_post` and `wp_update_post` are the critical functions you need to research, otherwise it's just like any other form handling.